# I regret his not having finished earlier. vs. I regret his not having finished by tomorrow. Both OK?

Tags: grammaticality

1. I regret his not having finished earlier. **Perfect gerund, action preceding regret.**
2. I regret his not having finished by tomorrow. **Perfect gerund, action preceding tomorrow.**

Is the 2nd. example correct, or should it be: I regret **his not finishing** by tomorrow?

Thank you.

Comment: To regret his "not having finished by tomorrow" is nonsense. Tomorrow is not yet here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Regret may not be the best verb. How about: I dread his not having finished this by 3 pm. tomorrow. Is that OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use the second example at all, in either of the forms you suggest. You can't regret something that is in the future. Regret means wishing something hadn't happened, so you can only feel regret after it has occurred.

One way you could put it is to say "I regret that he is unlikely to finish by tomorrow.". You are already feeling that it is unlikely. The feeling has already occurred, so you can feel regret for it.

Comment: Thanks. How about another verb: I dread his not having finished by tomorrow. Is that possible?

Comment: Dread is the wrong verb. To dread is to feel a very strong fear, for example of imminent death. I am slightly worried/worried/very worried that he may not finish by tomorrow.

Comment: That is possible, because dread relates to something that hasn't happened yet. However it is a very strong emotion, so you might want to consider whether worry or concerned might be more appropriate. "I worry about his not having finished by tomorrow" would be correct for example, or "I am concerned about his not having finished by tomorrow".